# Not able to Login in Login Form

Tags: jsp, servlets, authentication

I have Created an Login Webpage To login in sites.
Whenever i try to login it,it does not respond anything,but if i click on  sign'in button,then first it will give me a message that Email or Password is incorrect(which i have inserted this code in my servlet ) as  fields are empty,but after this process if i again enter credentials it allows me to login.

i mean First i have to click on sign'in button than servlet will give email or password incorrect,than after entering credentials in it it will allow me to login.

Jsp code of login

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>iCliniX</title>
<%@ include file="controls/css.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="controls/js.jsp" %>
</head>
<body>



<div class="account-container login">
 
 <div class="content clearfix">
  
  <form action="../AdminLoginServlet" method="post">
  
   <h1>Sign In</h1>  
   
   <div class="login-fields">
    
    <p>Sign in using your registered account:</p>
    
    <div class="field">
     <label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" class="login username-field" />
    </div> <!-- /field -->
    
    <div class="field">
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" class="login password-field"/>
    </div> <!-- /password -->
    
   </div> <!-- /login-fields -->
   
   <div class="login-actions">
    
    <span class="login-checkbox">
     <%
      String value = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("registration");
      if(value!=null){
       out.print(value);
      }
     %>
    </span>
         
    <input type="submit" class="button btn btn-secondary btn-large" value="Sign In" />
    
   </div> <!-- .actions -->
   
   
  </form>
  
 </div> <!-- /content -->
 
</div> <!-- /account-container -->

<!-- Text Under Box -->
<div class="login-extra">
  <a href="forgotpassword.jsp">Forgot Password</a>
</div> <!-- /login-extra -->



</body>

</html>
```

Servelt Script of jsp file.
AdminLoginServelt.java

```js
package com.iclinix.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


@WebServlet("/AdminLoginServlet")
public class AdminLoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  
 }

 
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  String email = request.getParameter("username");
  String pass = request.getParameter("password");
  HttpSession s = request.getSession();
  try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iclinix","root","root");
   Statement st = con.createStatement();
   String mail = null, password = null;
   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from tbl_admin_details where email='"+email+"'");
   while(rs.next()){
    mail = rs.getString("email");
    password = rs.getString("password");
   }
   if(mail!=null && password!=null &&email.equals(mail)&&pass.equals(password)){
    response.sendRedirect("cpaneliclinix/index.jsp");
   }
   else{
    s.setAttribute("registration", "Email Or Password are Wrong!!!");
    response.sendRedirect("cpaneliclinix/login.jsp");
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {

  }
 }

}
```

I hope you got my question.

Answer (score 0):

Change the form action as below, Since ../AdminLoginServlet is an invalid url

```
<form action="AdminLoginServlet" method="post">
```

Also, in the servlet do the below changes related to urls in sendRedirect.

```
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");//cpaneliclinix/index.jsp replaced
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");//cpaneliclinix/login.jsp replaced
```

Make sure you have index.jsp & login.jsp files in your root context location. I.e in WebContent folder if you are using eclipse.